# Differences between Professional, Enterprise, Unlimited, Developer editions

Tags: professional-edition, developer-edition, editions

I am about to sit my platform dev 1 certification and while doing practice questions I keep coming up against the different types of editions. I am not sure what unique characteristics each one has and how they differ from each other.

I keep getting these questions wrong and cannot find a comprehensive list of why you would use one over the other.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resources change over time, but you should always be able to simply search `salesforce editions feature comparison` and look through the results. The [top result](https://www.salesforce.com/editions-pricing/sales-cloud/) for me seems like what you want. You can expand and collapse sections as desired.

[image: Compare editions and features]

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few differences, not only in the features available and licensing but also on limits

Here's a full comparison between the editions

https://c1.sfdcstatic.com/content/dam/web/en_ie/www/datasheets/DS_SalesCloud_EdCompare.pdf

http://www.salesforceupdates.com/salesforce-edition-comparison-pdf/